# Which way of these two pattern matching is more preferred?

Tags: performance, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml, preference

I'm just curious, these two functions would do the same thing. But which one should I use?

```
let f a =
    match a with
        b -> a;; 
let f a =
    match a with
        b -> b;;
```

Or it just depends on your preference?
I feel the second one would be better but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Performance wise there is no difference. Style-wise `b -> a` is a bit problematic because you have an unused variable `b`. `_ -> a` would make more sense. Other than that, it's just preference.

Personally I would prefer `_ -> a` over `b -> b` because it doesn't introduce an extra variable.

PS: I assume in your real code there are more cases than just `b` - otherwise you could just write `let f a = a`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in your particular example I would rewrite using `function`

```
let f = function
      | b -> b
```